# How to store the generated txt file in the BinaryField

Tags: python, file, text, store

```
file = open("text1.txt", 'w')
file.write("Hello World")
file.close()
```

I have a binary field which is storetext

```
storetext= fields.Binary(string='Text File')
```

How can I store the txt file in storetext field?

Comment: What storetext field?   Please read [mcve]

Comment: @wwii It was at the beginning where I indicated storetext,i'm sorry but I edited it now

Comment: The `fields` module I know about doesn't have a `Binary` class. Can you provide a link to the docs for that module?

Comment: Have you tried `BinaryField` instead of `Binary`..?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
with open('text1.txt') as fin:
    storetext = fields.Binary(fin.read())
```